# How could I copy information from multiple cells that share a common feature into one cell?

Tags: google, google-sheets-cell-format, microsoft-excel

I have a list of codes that are each assigned to a specific bigger case code and I would like to put a list all of the smaller codes that share one bigger case code in one cell. for example

D2-D6 are a
01
02
03
04
05
and C2-C3 is
1

1. I want to group all the codes in the D column that share a 1 figure in the C column so the cell of my dreams would read "01,02". Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web app are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can first `FILTER` your range so that you're just left with the rows that you want. This would look like this `=FILTER(C2:D6, C2:C6 = 1)`. Then you'd need to somehow join the values in cells you've filtered. You could use `TEXTJOIN` for this `=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, TO_TEXT(F6), TO_TEXT(F7))`. I have cells from column F in my `TEXTJOIN` because that is where my filtered range went.

Note: I've tested my answer on Google Sheets but it is not clear from your question whether you are using Google Sheets or MS Excel.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Not all the questions should be answered. For details please read [answer].